# angular.js ui-route how catch route or url or params after reject?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to capture the url params or route or when the state is rejected:

define state

```
app.config(['$stateProvider',
function($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider.state('categories', {
  url: '/categories',
  templateUrl: 'categories/views/index.html',
  resolve: {
   loadRoute: app.loadRoute
  }
 });
}
]);
```

define resolve event , default reject

```
app.loadRoute = function ($q, $timeout) {
var deferred = $q.defer();
$timeout(deferred.reject);

return deferred.promise;
};
```

and run for init catch error reject

```
app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError',
  function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {       
//.....
  });
}]);
```

if my url is eg  ***/categories?param=1&paramtwo=2*** i want cacth this url for when validate continue this url

> ***how cath this url?*** on event reject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a few suggestions:

- First, take a look at the [ui-router documentation for state change events](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events).
- Get the state URL and params using the arguments of the watcher.
- Use the `error` argument in your watcher to check for different errors.
- Fix your call to `deferred.reject()`

---

#### 1. Getting the URL and parameters

- You don't need to use `$location`.
- Since you're using ui-router, you can get them with `toState.url` and `toParams`.

---

#### 2. Using the `error` argument in `$stateChangeError`

You can add an `error` argument to the  $stateChangeError event watcher like so:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error){ ... })
```

As the documentation says,

> It's important to note that if you have any errors in your `resolve functions` (javascript errors, non-existent services, etc) they will not throw traditionally. You must listen for this $stateChangeError event to catch ALL errors. Use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the $UrlRouter from reverting the URL to the previous valid location (in case of a URL navigation).

---

#### 3. Calling `deferred.reject()`

- **More importantly**, your call to `deferred.reject` in `$timeout(deferred.reject);` is not a function call.
- It should be `deferred.reject()` - (don't forget the parenthesis)

---

#### 4. Example

Here is an example that rejects the promise after one second with the error `'TEST_ERROR'`. The watcher logs that error, the intended state url, and it's params when the error is fired.

The resolve:

```js
  resolve: {
    errorObj: function($q, $timeout) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $timeout(function() {
        deferred.reject("TEST_ERROR");
      }, 1000);
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
```

The watcher:

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (error === "TEST_ERROR") {
    console.log("ERROR:", error, "URL:", toState.url, "PARAMS:", toParams);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service. There is [a working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/hMziUaV9yb3ZRm2X3M1Y?p=preview)

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$location',

  function ($rootScope, $state, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', 

    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
      console.log($location.url())
    });

}])
```

The doc cite:

> **`url([url]);`**
>
> This method is getter / setter.
> Return url (e.g. /path?a=b#hash) when called without any parameter.
> Change path, search and hash, when called with parameter and return $location.

```
// given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var url = $location.url();
// => "/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo"
```

The working demo shows that state defined as:

```
  .state('rejected', {
      url: "/rejected{any:.*}",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      resolve: {
        loadRoute: ['Loader', function(Loader){
          return Load.load()
        }]
      }
  })
```

when navigated like this:

```
<a href="#/rejected?par1=x&amp;para2=y">
<a href="#/rejected/other">
```

will log into console

```
/rejected?par1=x&amp;para2=y
/rejected/other
```

Check the [demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hMziUaV9yb3ZRm2X3M1Y?p=preview)