# How to pass header info with ui-router?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angular app that communicates with a rails back end via a token based authentication system.

When I was using ngRoute I had an interceptor that would get the token from the cookie store and add it to the headers for each request made to the server.

Then it would listen for the status and redirect to login if the token was unauthorized.

How do I do this with ui-router? It doesn't seem to work the same way.

**Sharing the solution I came up with:**

```
angular.module 'saAuthentication', []

  .config ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->
    $stateProvider
      .state 'login',
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'app/authentication/sessions/login.html',

  .run ($rootScope, $state, localStorageService) ->
    $rootScope.$on "$stateChangeStart", (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) ->
      if localStorageService.cookie.get('X-User-Token') == null
        event.preventDefault()
        $state.go('login', null, { notify: false }).then (state) ->
          $rootScope.$broadcast('$stateChangeSuccess', state, null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this very easily by using `$stateChangeError`

#### Suggestions

- Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28778015/angular-js-ui-route-how-catch-route-or-url-or-params-after-reject/28778830#28778830) I posted for a similar question.
- Take a look at the [`ui-router` documentation for state change events](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events).
- Read the documentations for the following services: [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

#### How-to

- Use a promise in a `resolve` to accept or reject the authentication for a given state, and
- Handle a `$stateChangeError` to go to a different state if the promise is rejected.

#### Example

Declare the state with a resolve in your `.config()` like so:

```js
app.config(['$stateProvider',function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('profile', {
    url: '/profile',
    template: '<h1>Hello authenticated user!</h1>',
    resolve: {
     authState: function($q, $timeout) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        //Simulate $http request with a $timeout
        $timeout(function() {
          deferred.reject("AUTH_REQUIRED");
        }, 1000);
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    }
  });
}]);
```

And set the `$stateChangeError` watcher in `.run()` like so:

```js
app.run(function ($rootScope,   $state,   $stateParams) {
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
      console.log("ERROR:", error, "URL:", toState.url, "PARAMS:", toParams);
      //not authenticated, go to login instead of the route change
      $state.go('login');
    }
  });
});
```

#### Explanation

- In the example above, I use a `$timeout` to simulate an error with authentication.

  - It rejects the promise after one second with the error `'AUTH_REQUIRED'`.
  - `$stateChangeError` watcher catches this error, and responds accordingly.
- What you would do is use the [`$http` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to make your authentication request, and...

  - Accept the promise in `.success()`,
  - Reject the promise in `.error()`.

Here is the general usage example for making a request straight from the [`$http` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

```js
// Simple GET request example :
$http.get('/someUrl').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

**In `.success()`, you can check the headers and accept/reject the promise accordingly.** You should reject the promise in `.error()`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hmm, I was able to get it to work with: ```event.preventDefault();
    $state.go('login', null, { notify: false }).then (state) ->
      $rootScope.$broadcast('$stateChangeSuccess', state, null)``` -- is this a bad way to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a "bad" way to do it, but it seems redundant. By manually broadcasting `$stateChangeSuccess`, you're losing the arguments that could come in handy later. The `$stateChangeError` listener is meant for this exact purpose. Edit: see teleaziz's last comment.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in listening to the event, when using ui-router listen to `$stateChangeStart`.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
    function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    // redirect to login here if the token doesn't exist
    })
```

Comment: When I use $state.go inside the function, I get into what appears to be an infinite call loop. How do I redirect?

Comment: See my answer that I just posted. You can watch `$stateChangeError` for this purpose (not `$stateChangeStart`), combined with `event.preventDefault()` to avoid the infinite loop.

Comment: You don't want to prevent the default for all state changes. `$stateChangeError` is another way of solving the problem. Although, reading tokens from the `$cookieStore` is synchronous and doesn't need a promise, so you can simply add an `authenticate:true` to any state you want to guard and test on $stateChangeStart if the `toState.authenticate,' Nathan can you share your code?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question! I read over the "add the token to each request" part. I was thinking of changing to a different state IF the request to authenticate wasn't successful. And thanks for correcting me on prevent default.

Comment: @teleaziz I posted a code sample of what I came up with. What do you think?